# Algorithm for Cumulative Maximum with First Element Removal

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement a data structure for storing the cumulative maximum (cummax) list of a given list of integers with efficient remove-first-element operation. In a cumulative maximum list an element at index `i` is determined as the maximum number among all elements in the given list with indices less than or equal to `i`. For example, for the list `[10, 7, 8, 0, 3, 11]` the cumulative maximum list should be `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]`. Time complexity of constructing a cummax list is `O(n)` by simply iterating over all the elements and storing the maximum element so far.

The issue is that I want `removeFirst` operation to be more efficient than simply constructing the cummax list from scratch after it. For example, when removing the first element from the example list, the cummax list should become `[7, 8, 8, 8, 11]`. After removing another one, it should be `[8, 8, 8, 11]`.

Is it possible to make such a data structure with better time complexity (now it's `O(n)`) for removing the first element?

Comment: To verify the result you will have to look at each value in the cummax list, and that represents O(n). If you don't need to look at the cummax list, then you don't need to build it either and the removeFirst operation can have O(1) time complexity. In the latter case you only need to update the index where the remainder of the list starts. If at any moment you need to get the list, then build it at the same time: O(n), which is the time needed to look at the list anyway. Maybe I misunderstand the question, but then please clarify which is your expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

We can have a general solution using known "range minimum/maximum query" procedures. For any one element at index `j` with cumulative maximum first element (on the left) at index `i`, the value `cumulativeMax(j)` would be the same as `rangeMaximumQuery(i, j)`.